# Non partial update on elasticsearch node API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch.js

As the 2.0 docs [say](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-2-0.html#api-update-2-0), updates performed are partial - they do not override the whole document but only merge the existing one with the value given.

Is there a way to perform a full update using this API?

Comment: At Elasticsearch level, the old document gets deleted, the new one is indexed even if this is an update operation, don't forget that. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/docs-update.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply re-index the document using [`client.index`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-2-0.html#api-index-2-0), as if it was a new document, but using the same id.

A new version of the document will be indexed and stored, which will override the one stored previously.